# CRS centered on the 180 meridian?

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

The problem I'm dealing with is the old 180 meridian problem, except I'm not trying to plot or render shapes that cross it, I need to do intersections of lines that cross it. The only spherical function available in geotools appears to be orthodromic distance, so I need to do the intersections in 2d.

Can I take the naive approach and simply copy the WGS83 WKT and change the PM to 180? I can't use the UTM zones because my lines are long (airport to airport, i.e. Hong Kong to Vancouver).